# how to use soup.find_all() providing attrs starting with sometext

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I trying to scrape this website, [enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1 all the data which I want to scrape will be inserted in a div whose class gets dynamic value each time. wo what I want to find all those divs using soup.find_all() and provide starting string to its class.

this is my current code,

```
outerDivs = soup.find_all(attrs={"tabindex": "-1", "class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"})
```

what I want to get is to find_all() divs having attribute tabindex=1 and class starts with `ng-tns-...` `ng-star-inserted`. the only value that changes comes after `ng-tns` ... right now it looks like `ng-tns-c294-1 ng-star-inserted` please note `ng-star-inserted` always remains the same.

this is how I get the soup code.

```
       driver.get(
            f'https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page={currentpage}')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#search-results")))
        source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

current page increases by one each time to go to next page

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: @goalie1998 , Actually , I didn't becasue one I don't know regex, secondly I don't know how to use it with find_all() providing many attributes. I will appreciate your help

Comment: print all attributes using `elem.attrs.values()` and see how these called to get those

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I could not get your instruction

Comment: How are you getting the html, requests, urllib, selenium...?

Comment: @goalie1998   driver.get(
            f'https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page={currentpage}')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#search-results")))
        source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

Comment: Ok, using selenium. It also has page navigation that might be a little easier.

Comment: I alreay have written my whole code using beautiful soup, I just find out that the class attrs changes each time, so I only need to change that line code.

Comment: previously I used static class value {"class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"} which was working now I get empty data means we don't have such div having such class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the best with regex, so there might be a better way to do it, but this should do the trick:

```py
soup.find_all(attrs={"tabindex": "-1", "class": re.compile("^ng-tns.*ng-star-inserted$")})
```

It will only match a class that starts specifically with "ng-tns," has any number of characters, then ends specifically with "ng-star-inserted."